# How to iterate a list of Predicates

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming, predicate

I have a spring boot application and we have an application.yml with a set of feature flags on it

```
featureFlag:
    featureOne:true
    featureTwo:true
    featureThree:true
    featureFour:false
```

Then this file is read by a this class

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="featureFlag")
public class FeatureFlag{

private Boolean featureOne;
private Boolean featureTwo;
private Boolean featureThree;
private Boolean featureFour;
/*The predicates based on the feature flags*/

private Predicate<FeatureFlag> isFeatureFlagOneEnabled = featureFlag.isFeatureOne();
private Predicate<FeatureFlag> isFeatureFlagTwoEnabled = featureFlag.isFeatureTwo();
private Predicate<FeatureFlag> isFeatureFlagThreeEnabled = featureFlag.isFeatureThree();
private Predicate<FeatureFlag> isFeatureFlagFourEnabled = featureFlag.isFeatureFour();
}
```

I want to pass the actual predicate and iterate each one of them but I want to know if I can do a generic function that I pass the list of Predicates with its value to be tested and if all of them are true the function return me a true otherwise false

Then in this class add some code like this because I want to generate this list on demand, for example I have a client x that purchase featureOne and featureTwo, in this example I create a list like this

```
Set<Predicate<FeatureFlag>> rulesForClientX = new HashSet<>();
rulesForClientX.add(isFeatureFlagOneEnabled);
rulesForClientX.add(isFeatureFlagTwoEnabled);
```

Then I want to create a specific logic for that client and pass it the list of predicates previously created, but I think I would need something like this

```
Function<List<Predicate<FeatureFlag>>, Boolean> iteratePredicates = (predicates) -> { 
    //test each predicate and return true if all of them are true otherwise return false
}
```

Comment: "*... if all of them are true...*" - What do you mean by this? The two `Predicate`s you gave are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Well in my specific case I have a list of featureFlags that at the end we need to verify all of them are enabled in order to execute some block of code otherwise that block of code not suppose to be executed

Comment: looks like there is just no Java API exactly suitable for that, you would have to workaround that and build some extra code, not sure if `Stream.takeWhile()` or `Stream.dropWhile` can help: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile(java.util.function.Predicate)

Comment: A `Predicate` is not a value, but an unary function. It takes something (in the example given most probably an `Integer`) as an input and returns a `boolean`. Maybe  a combination of `stream()`ing the flags and `reduce(...)`ing them is what is needed.

Comment: Yes and that is my point, the code looks like the same in all of the scenarios I mean I am receiving something (Integer, Person object) and then it will return me a Boolean, that the why my question

Comment: then you should updated the exact scenario with data so that we can help you @jam

Comment: @jam where/how are the parameters for the predicates determined? Or do they all use the same predicate?

Comment: @Deadpool I just update to something more related to  my actual problem

Comment: @Turing85  I just update to something more related to my actual problem

Comment: This looks more like a `Provider`, not a `Predicate`. The name `isFeatureFlagOneEnabled` suggest that this method does not take any parameter and just returns a `boolean`.

Comment: I updated my answer but still can you show `FeatureFlag` class and method that takes input and returns boolean ? @jam

Comment: @Deadpool updated

Comment: I update accordingly, I do not know if make more sense, otherwise I will need to create a github project thanks @Deadpool

Comment: Sorry can you please update the code in git @jam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Chain `Predicate`s

What you should look forward to is chaining the predicates that you have.

> I pass the list of Predicates with its value to be tested and if all
>   of them are true the function return me a true otherwise false

Based on your requirements this should look like;

```
public Predicate<FeatureFlag> chainPredicates(Set<Predicate<FeatureFlag>> predicates) {
    return predicates.stream()
                     .reduce(Predicate::and) // all true
                     .orElse(p -> false); // or false
}
```

#### Consume `Predicate`

Further now, you can consume this single `Predicate` easily as

```
boolean testFeatureFlag(Set<Predicate<FeatureFlag>> predicates, FeatureFlag value) {
    return chainPredicates(predicates).test(value);
}
```

or on a collection say a `List<FeatureFlag>` to filter out specific `FeatureFlag`s as:

```
List<FeatureFlag> selectiveFeatures(Set<Predicate<FeatureFlag>> predicates, List<FeatureFlag> featureFlags) {
    Predicate<FeatureFlag> flagPredicate  = chainPredicates(predicates);
    return featureFlags.stream()
            .filter(flagPredicate)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Yes that exactly what I am trying to do, I mean I want to create very specific functions and then construct bigger functions based on the smaller ones, will try this

Answer (score 4):

You can create a method that accepts `Set<Predicate<FeatureFlag>>` and  value, then you can stream set of predicates and use [allMatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-)

```
public boolean testPredicates(Set<Predicate<FeatureFlag>> predicates, Integer value) {
  return predicates.stream().allMatch(pre->pre.test(value));

 }
```

Comment: Using `pre.test(value)` would require value to be of type  `FeatureFlag`

Comment: Actually the code in the post is not really clear to me, I'm asking to OP to upload to git so that i can take a look @Naman and you are right it should be `FeatureFlag`